# CPLEX returns no solution with deterministic time limit

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, cplex, convex-optimization, docplex

I'm working with CPLEX using the python API (Docplex).

If I set the time limit in seconds with `model.set_time_limit(60)` the solver returns the best integer feasible solution notifying that the time is exceeded and everything is fine.

Now I want to set the timeout in a deterministic manner, so I'm using `model.parameters.dettimelimit = 600000`.
The problem is that now the solver doesn't return any solution even if the solution status (`model.get_cplex().solution.get_status()`) return the state 131: [CPXMIP_DETTIME_LIM_FEAS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.8.0.0?topic=api-cpxmip-dettime-lim-feas), in fact the logs show that an integer feasible solution has been found:

```
 13937  8815       -0.2108     0       -0.2108       -0.0110   531179   94.77%
 14185  8946       -0.2108     4       -0.2108       -0.0120   537954   94.29%
 Elapsed time = 105.69 sec. (59749.84 ticks, tree = 258.03 MB, solutions = 19)
 * 14193  8945      integral     0       -0.2108       -0.0127   537955   93.98%
 * 14194  9005      integral     0       -0.2108       -0.0142   542020   93.27%
```

How can I force CPLEX to return the best incumbent solution even with the deterministic timelimit?

Comment: It sounds like a bug, maybe you should contact Cplex support directly

Comment: What happens when you call the method to get the solution?

Comment: @prubin The `model.solve()` method returns None meaning no feasible solution. While the `solve_details()` status is deterministic time limit exceeded

Comment: Have you tried with latest cplex version ? CPLEX 22.1 ?